# Sci-fi book about a female agent for a galactic government and a male who lives in some kind of dome

Tags: story-identification, books

All I can remember is that it takes place on several planet locations. There's two main characters; a female agent for a galactic government and a male who, if I remember correctly, lives in some kind of dome that gets attacked.

Comment: What language was it in, when was it written approximately, do you remember any cover-art? Check-out our [story ID checklist](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and see if it jogs your memory.

Comment: @Gabriel - An anonymous user has attempted to edit your question. If that person is you, and you've lost access to the account you used to post this question, please merge your new account with the old one by following the instructions provided [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts). In doing so, you'll regain the ability to edit this question without approval from others, leave comments within this thread, and mark a correct answer as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer), if one is posted.

Answer (score 1):

There aren't many details in the question (date read, language etc.) but I'll take a shot in the dark:

What about ['A Memory called Empire'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Memory_Called_Empire) by Arkady Martine?

The novel is about a female diplomat visiting the capital of a galactic empire. It includes an attack on the (male) Emperor's palace. The part that doesn't match  is the dome structure but it's possible the palace is described that way; I don't remember that detail.